# I need a TypeScript library to, format money and numbers, perform localization operations

Tags: typescript, money-format, numeral.js

I'm developing a mobile application using React-Native and TypeScript super-set. I am looking for a format library in which I can perform numbers, currencies, dates, numbers and localizations.

I've used the Numeral JS library before, but the format range is too narrow, and I tried the autoNumeric library, but I didn't have the possibility to use it because @types was not available.

Apart from this, I did not get the efficiency I wanted from many libraries. I'd love to hear your suggestions.

Comment: Did you consider momentjs and lodash?

Comment: firstly thank you for the suggestion, but I guess the libraries you mentioned don't seem to benefit me much about money formats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if **@types** is not available you can still use the **autoNumeric** library by adding your own type definition.

1. Add a `@types` folder inside project folder
2. Create a file named .d.ts

[image: Add @types folder here]

3. Inside the file add the following line

   `declare module 'autonumeric';`
4. Add the path of the newly created folder in `tsconfig.json` under `compilerOptions` like so

   `"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "src/@types"]`

   *Note: "node_modules/@types" will already be present. You only need to add the newly path of the new folder.*
5. Save. Run `npm i` and then start the application.